# Functional parameters in Go functions

Tags: function, go, types, golang-migrate

Is there a way to pass a function(which can be generic) to another function?
I know that with known input types and return types we can pass a function but a generic approach is needed

Comment: There are no generics in current version of Go. They won't be available until Go 2 gets released.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the [Go2 proposal on generic: "Type Parameters - Draft Design"](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md), I am not sure you would be able to pass as parameter a generic function without explicitly specify the type used by said function

See "[Instantiating a function](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md#instantiating-a-function)"

> Go normally permits you to refer to a function without passing any arguments, producing a value of function type.
> **You may not do this with a function that has type parameters; all type arguments must be known at compile time.**
> That said, you can instantiate the function, by passing type arguments, but you don't have to call the instantiation. This will produce a function value with no type parameters.

```golang
// PrintInts is type func([]int).
var PrintInts = Print[int]
```